# OR Tools - nodes duplicates, only one in the solution

Tags: or-tools

I have VRPTW example from OR Tools and I have set of nodes, that contains duplicates of nodes - it represents possibility of two and more time-windows for the same node. There cannot be more that one node like this in solution. Thus I need constraint which will ensure that there are not duplicate nodes in one solution. For example node with index 5 is variant of node with index 21 only with different time window and there can be only node 5 or node 21, not both together. Could someone please give me some hint/code which I could test?

I have tried to look at some function like model.NewBoolVar() or model.AddBoolAnd(), but I don't know how to use them to make constraint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing different solvers.
There are 3 different solvers ok n. Or-tools:

- the routing library
- CP-SAT
- a linear solver wrapper with multiple implementations and backends.

You are mixing the routing library and cp-sat apis.
What you want is a disjunction.
Search for AddDisjunction()

Comment: Thanks! AddDisjunction() did the actual job.